# Unity Road Architect System Extrusions not working in URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am facing a issue as I recorded in my video, I cant use the wizard manager and the extrusions are not working. I'm presently using Unity 2021.3.18f1 URP project.
I am a Beginner and please help me solve this issue

please check this video : https://youtu.be/Le7C23Ncr6A

I tried manythings and i can't go forward without this.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution and I wanna share it.

I changed the package file location from Assets/Packages/Road-Architect to Assets/Road-Architect and when I done this, It actually works. If not works, then remove the package and import it again inside the Assets folder directly.